# SQL: pulling data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

My end goal is to have the results displayed as table 3 below

[image]

I'm leveraging this:

```
select 
    table1.item,
    table1.cymode,
    sum(cysales),
    sum(pysales)
from 
    table1
left join 
    table2 on table1.item = table2.item
group by 
    1, 2
```

The left join above doesn't give the desired results.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem that `sum(cysales)` is 20? (After you join, there are two rows so summing them is going to be 20.) Or do you get an error? (If so, specifying your DB and the error message will help, but not all DBMSes support using numbers in the `group by`)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the result example it seems that the first sum you are using is not correct. The right query should be like this (I am imagine how the query should work only looking at the example)

```sql
select 
    table1.item,
    table1.cymode,
    cysales,
    sum(pysales)
from 
    table1
left join 
    table2 on table1.item = table2.item
group by 
    1, 2
```

This is because the join is the first operation made on the query, so it would result on something like this:

| Item | cyMode | Shipment id | cysales | Item | pyMode | Shipment id | pysales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Online | Y | 10 | X | Offline | Z | 15 |
| X | Online | Y | 10 | X | Free | A | 10 |

Then they would be grouped by item and cymode, and sum all the rows resulting 20 on cysales if you use the sum aggregation, or 10 if you do not use the sum aggregation on cysales:

| Item | cyMode | cysales | pysales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Online | 20 | 25 |

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two records in Table2, when joined to Table1, the Table1 will end up like having two records as well of identical rows. When do the sum, it will end up cysales=20, pysales=25 which is incorrect.

You can aggregate (SUM) each table’s value first then Join them. You can use CTE, or a subquery.

```
WITH Cte_Table1 AS 
(
  SELECT Item, cymode, SUM(cysales) cysales
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Item, cymode
),
Cte_Table2 AS 
AS 
(
  SELECT Item, SUM(pysales) pysales
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY Item
)
SELECT t1.Item, t1.cymode, t1.cysales, t2.pysales
FROM Cte_Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Cte_Table2 t2 on t1.Item=t2.Item;
```